# Join 2 tables in mysql, return rows that don't relate

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

table 1: questions (id, question, date)

table 2: answers (id, question_id, answer, date)

a question can have more than 1 answer, some questions don't have answers. I want to output only unanswered questions

a query like `SELECT * FROM`questions`,`answers`WHERE questions.id!=answers.question_id group by questions.id` doesn't work

Can someone help a newbie like me, I'm so lost in all this mysql stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Q.id, Q.question, Q.date
FROM questions Q LEFT JOIN answers A ON (Q.id = A.question_id)
WHERE A.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, question, date
FROM questions q 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM answers a 
     WHERE a.question_id = q.id)
```

OR

```
SELECT id, question, date
FROM questions q 
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT id, question, date
FROM questions q 
WHERE q.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT question_id FROM answers WHERE question_id IS NOT NULL)
                                 /* If question_id can't be NULL this is not needed*/
```

Comment: thank you. didn't expected it to be so quick. thank you again, it works. love mysql

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM
questions,answers
WHERE answers.answer = null or answers.answer = "";